# Regular expression for website url

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

A URL should start with `http://` or `www.`

```
http://google.com
```

or

```
www.google.com
```

My Regular expression is:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^http(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([.\w][0-9a-zA-Z])(:(0-9))(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_])?$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
```

My code is working fine for `http://google.com` but not for `www.google.com`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: what infos do you want to extract from the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
'#((https?://|www\.)([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)#'
```

Comment: I like it except the amount of capturing it does, make some (most) groups non-capturing and you'll get my +1

Comment: It's been a long time since I have dealt with regexes. This I had posted on my blog a long time ago.